# Convert all strokes to fills in Sketch

Tags: svg, sketch-app, stroke, fill

Is there a way to do this? This is my first time trying to make glyphicons and icomoon ignores strokes. I have quite a few, so was hoping there were some veteran designers that could point me in the right direction to the quickest way of converting strokes to fills.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it.

Select the shapes that you want to convert and choose Layer → Convert to Outlines

Just select all if you want everything to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch has removed support for convert-to-outline for paths.
You can do it by exporting your item as svg from sketch and then converting it to shapes-only using this free online tool:
https://www.ofoct.com/image-converter/svg-optimizer.html

Comment: Can you please include a source for that change?

Comment: What did you select in the online tool to do shapes only?

Comment: @MattHudson It is not straightforward. Choose one of the files you want to convert and play around with the settings. Out of the default selections I deselected 'convert Shape To Path', 'transforms With One Path' & 'merge Paths'. But it didn't work for all the files I wanted to convert. For others I turned one ON and other OFF and it worked.

Comment: That's not correct, or the option is back. It's available in Sketch 94